# Resharper edit template for Create derived type

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, refactoring, resharper

After hitting "Create derived type" a class is produced that inherits from the selected interface or superclass, with a default template visible in the screenshot.

[image: after creating derived type]

Similarly to the templates that are used elsewhere in Resharper, I would like to edit the template that is generated?

- [I cannot find any place to do that under Resharper -> Templates Explorer?](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Templates__Template_Basics__Template_Types.html)
- [Unfortunately no answers here either](http://devnet.jetbrains.com/thread/437799)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't a template, the class declaration is created directly, so can't be edited. Out of interest, what do you want to change?

Comment: i would like to make it something like `public class Deployment : $BASECLASS$, IDeployment' Can i submit a feature request somewhere, for consistency and flexibility would make sense to make that a template too..